# Is a polynomial function a rational function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, terminology, rational-functions

It's my first time on this forum so please forgive any errors in the presentation of my question.

My query refers to definitions of polynomials and rational functions. I have just started Ferrar's 'Higher Alegbra for Schools' and have become bogged down in the definitions. I have attached link but will try and explain myself first.

The first chapter begins with a number of definitions, in particular definitions of polynomial, rational and algebraic functions. *Polynomials* are defined strictly for positive exponents (n), whilst *rational* as the ratio of two polynomials. Mr Ferrar then goes on to describe and define *algebraic* functions. His example (see link) is a quadratic in $y$ with polynomials in $x$. He then goes on to define, in general, that algebraic functions are the same as the example but with rational functions of $x$.

Herein lies my lack of understanding. Put plainly my question is this,

> Does a polynomial function imply rational?

By modern definitions it would appear so, but I am unable to see how Mr Ferrar's generality is to include polynomials as his definition seems inadequate.

Please forgive any ignorance on my part, I'm sure there's a subtlety here that I'm missing but I'm not quite sure what it is.

The book can be found here:

https://archive.org/details/higheralgebrafor0000ferr/page/4/mode/2up

Pages 2, 3 and 4 give details of my post.

Many thanks in advance for any advice given.

Comment: yes, polynomials are rational functions. And that _does_ follow from the definition: if $p$ is a polynomial then $p=p/1$.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking:  "is every polynomial a rational function?"  If so, the answer is Yes.  Constant functions, like $1$, are polynomials so, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial, we can write $p(x)=\frac {p(x)}1$ to exhibit $p(x)$ as the quotient of two polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link won't show pages 2 and 3 to non-subscribers (I'm guessing) so I can't tell what the book really says.

When you say polynomials are defined strictly for positive exponents, this is a bit vague.   We would consider

$$3x^3 - 2x^2+\frac{1}{2}x -5$$

to be a polynomial, even though the last term is really $-5x^0$ and the exponent is not positive.

Therefore

$$1$$

is a polynomial and therefore

$$3x^3 - 2x^2+\frac{1}{2}x -5=\frac{3x^3 - 2x^2+\frac{1}{2}x -5}{1}$$

is a rational function.

I think this is the answer to your question:  If a function is a polynomial, then it is also a rational function.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion due to wording of my post. I should have said exponent n is a positive integer.

Comment: @GRL  But do you mean ALL the exponents are positive integers?  If so, constants like $-5$ and $1$ would not be polynomials, because the exponent on $x$ is $0$ which is not positive.

Comment: I am sorry,  I mean the definition states the leading term of a polynomial has the form ax^n where n is a positive integer; if this is correct then I don't understand how constants can be polynomials by his definition - however I do take your point.  I wish I could show you the text to remove ambiguity. It is free to register to above link and I don't pay any subscription. Many thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Saying that polynomials are not rational functions is like (exactly like) saying integers are not rational numbers.  This is an old book, and maybe it has outdated terminology.

Comment: Many thanks for all your help and advice. I will not dwell on the Mr Ferrar's definitions in this instance.

Comment: @GRL: I can't see the pages of the book where the definitions are given, but I *do* see page 4 where item 1 of Examples I A asks "whether the following functions are polynomial or rational" with the specific function of $\frac{1}{3x}$. Does the book classify that function —with its *constant* numerator— as rational?

Comment: I’m not sure but will check with solutions shortly and reply. Thank you spotting this as I hadn’t. This may help in giving a definitive answer to my question.

Comment: @Blue: It does indeed state that $\frac{1}{3x}$ is a rational function. Many thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @B. Goddard: Many thanks once again. Your explanation fits with solution mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the analogous case in geometry of the definition of points, line segments,
and rectangles. A point has no length or area. A line segment has non zero length,
but no area, and a rectangle has non zero length and width. These are regarded as
three mutually exclusive concepts in classical geometry.

The situation in algebra is different. A constant
is regarded as a
polynomial of degree zero. A rational function is the quotient of two polynomials
where either of them are allowed to be constant. Thus all polynomials are also
considered to be rational functions and all constants are also considered to be
polynomials.

Mr. Ferrar is probably working with a context closer to the geometric one described
earlier. Thus constants, polynomials and rational functions are mutually exclusive. This is acceptable if the definitions are clear about the edge cases.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I believe think the constants, polynomials and rational functions are  treated as mutually exclusive. It is the edge cases that are the causing confusion. If I state, 'in general, that algebraic functions are the same as the example but with rational functions of x' then I fail to see how the example is acceptable as it uses only polynomials in x.